# Using another entire answer (not comment) unattributed in your own

Tags: discussion, answers

I previously had a top-rated answer on a question. It was short and to the point (one sentence and a command), and given the votes - all that most people needed to solve their issue.

Another user came along and included my entire answer (without attribution), and then continued to provide some additional information. This answer is now the top-rated one.

I proposed an edit to the offending answer which referenced my original answer instead of including all of it, but one moderator rejected it without even addressing my issue and instead decided to focus on formatting changes.

I feel like my answer was plagiarized and the new author is receiving un-deserved credit and reputation. Ideally, the new answer should have referenced mine, instead of including it.

**How should answers who include other entire answers on the same question page be handled?**

*Note: This is different than the dilemma of whether to allow answers to use information in comments. I see this has been thoroughly discussed and general consensus reached.*

**Clarification:** This question is regarding the topic in general -- not my specific incident. I have seen this happen to other users over time. Since the issue was discussed at length regarding comments, I think discussion for answers would be constructive.

Comment: What was the question/answer, and what comment did you write for the custom moderator flag? If it's [the answer I think it is (by looking at your answers)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14903842/2422013), the two answers are similar (yours and the person you're accusing) but I wouldn't say there's any pinching of answers going on. Plus, it took place in September 2013; what makes you bring this up almost three years later?

Comment: That is not the answer I am talking about, but the actual answer of mine shouldn't matter.

Comment: Then there's definitely *no plagiarism going on*. The moderator was correct to decline the flag..

Comment: This question of mine is not just regarding my specific incident. I was probably not the first, and won't be the last so I think this is worth discussing regardless of whether I was plagiarized or not.

Comment: Also, how can you place judgement when you don't know which question/answer I am referring to?

Comment: I get that, but your specific instance still applies here. I've looked through all your 7 answers, and I can't see anything out of order. There's a couple of cases of similar answers (specifically [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351260/how-to-check-which-php-extensions-have-been-enabled-disabled-in-ubuntu-linux-12/32831878#32831878)), but they definitely are not plagiarized from your answer.

Comment: You should suggest an edit to add attribution and comment on the post first. If that doesn't work (or your edit is rejected), raise a custom flag on a post if it plagiarizes your content without attribution. However in this case your flag was declined because *there was no plagiarized content*. To me this simply sounds like a 'someone else's answer was better than mine' moan...

Comment: Sorry, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33866153/176646) is *clearly* not plagiarizing [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32831878/176646). Plagiarism would be copying a long code snippet or explanation word-for-word. The only thing that's the same in both answers is trivial: the command `php -m` and the word "modules." If that's plagiarism, you're guilty of plagiarizing the PHP manual.

Comment: The first part of the answer's solution is the entire solution I provided. The offending answer could have completely stood on its own by simply referencing my answer instead of including it. It's redundant at best. Had my answer been longer, I think your opinions would be different. Length should not matter -- it's the solution to the question that should be the focus.

Comment: This question is about *you* complaining you lost some Internet points because someone's answer was better than yours, who posted a similar (but not identical) answer with more detail than your own.

Comment: @cybermonkey - You have provided your input, but I disagree. The issue at hand is part of something larger. Others have discussed at length the dilemma of using other's comments as answers and claiming credit for them - so this is something I feel is worth discussing. Reputation points are part of what sustains this community so your condescending remark about complaining about "internet points" looks like trolling. If there isn't anything constructive you have to contribute to this anymore, please stop commenting.

Comment: @TheKarateKid Then use an example other than your own. Please thoroughly read through the [help]. There hasn't been any discussion 'at length' here in any sense of the word about the topic.

Comment: @cybermonkey I did not mention my specific question and answer in this topic - so your reasoning is still invalid.

Comment: How so? The community obviously disagrees with you judging by the current state of your question. It's generally considered that if you comment an answer and another user actually *posts* it as an answer (without attribution), you lose out and there's nothing much you can do apart from nicely commenting on the answer to attribute the answer (or part of) to you. It's in your best interest (as an answerer) to write the answer ASAP (remember good quality and such...); you can always delete it if it turns out to be incorrect (and you get a badge for that).

Comment: @cybermonkey You don't even seem to know what's going on here. My answer was NOT a comment. I made this very clear. So now, you are debating when you're not even properly informed.

Comment: @TheKarateKid I never said your answer was a comment. I said it above, and I'll say it again; if you see any answers *directly copying another* (i.e, *not* what happened in your case), raise a custom flag explaining clearly what the problem is. From experience, such answers rarely last more than a few minutes and are exterminated quickly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112448/discussion-between-cybermonkey-and-thekaratekid).

Answer (score 10):

There is no plagiarism here.

This is the problem with providing a one line sentence as an answer, it doesn't hold up well over time. Answers should be written to stand the test of time.

With regards to the [specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32831878/1026459), literally a one liner

> You can view which modules (compiled in) are available via terminal through php -m

Which was posted Sep 28 '15 at 21:09 by you, it is *not possible to even claim that as the first time the point was made on that post* because [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351260/how-to-check-which-php-extensions-have-been-enabled-disabled-in-ubuntu-linux-12/33866153#comment37650138_24351260)

> Try this in terminal php -m you will see the available modules. – rahilwazir Jun 22 '14 at 12:35

Was made well over a year before the answer containing that information. If anything, the answer was merely a re-purposed comment in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your input but the intent of my question was for discussion regarding everybody in SO, not just my incident. I have seen this happen to others and when it happened to me I wanted to take initiative to discuss.

Comment: @TheKarateKid It *didn't* happen to you, as it has been pointed out *countless times*.

Answer (score 1):

[What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered) is pretty clear on this, specifically point number 2:

> If it looks like a minor, single incident, **editing the attribution in
>   is the way to go**. You can do that yourself, either directly or through
>   a suggested edit. Put the attribution in front of the copied material,
>   and put everything into blockquotes that isn't the OP's original
>   speech. Use nice wording, like From the Wikipedia Article on xyz.
>
> If it looks like there is an egregious pattern of plagiarism, and
>   deletions seem necessary, flag for moderator attention. Explain that
>   you believe the answer has been plagiarized, and paste the source URL
>   into a comment underneath, say Plagiarism: copied without attribution
>   from ....
>
> If your flag gets declined, flag again and/or raise the issue on Meta.
>   Here is previous discussion.

To answer your question:

> How should answers who include other entire answers on the same
>   question page be handled?

You **should edit the answer** to insert the attribution or/and post a comment as in the quote above. If the edit is rejected and the author of the answer has not edited to include the attribution, I would *then* flag for moderator attention explaining the incident.

---

The problem in your case is that the answer was not plagiarised, and as [Travis J said in their answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323409/using-another-entire-answer-not-comment-unattributed-in-your-own/323412#323412):

> This is the problem with providing a one line sentence as an answer, it doesn't hold up well over time. Answers should be written to stand the test of time.

The other answer contained much more detail than yours. Furthermore, it was not a moderator who rejected your edit, but rather, the community.